# OpenCV and MacOS native rendering in C++

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, core-graphics, core-video

tldr; How do I display a cv::Mat on MacOS natively in a C++ project?

I was having performance problems with waitKey and it was suggested that I use my operating system's native rendering functions for better performance. Performance matters to me as I am doing live effect processing on videos displaying in real-time.

I did some research and discovered that on OSX (my operating system), CoreVideo and CoreGraphics are used for video processing and rendering. However, the complexity of the documentation is making my head spin and I'm not quite sure how to integrate it with the Mat datatype I'm working with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Strange enough, if I pass WINDOW_OPENGL to namedWindow, waitFor's delay drops drastically, but imshow jumps up.

Comment: This is also a useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129683/does-opengl-display-image-faster-than-opencv

Comment: Information about imshow being slow may be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837796/cvimshow-sometimes-is-very-slow

Comment: I'm now as an alternative trying to use SDL.

Comment: Using SDL2 for the UI portion and getting rid of highgui did the trick! No need for Mac specific stuff so far.